# How can I use sourcemaps with gulp-sass + gulp-minify-css + autoprefixer + rename?

Tags: css, node.js, sass, gulp

I'm currently using a gulp workflow that uses a `createSassTask()` method to generate a task for each of several different httpddocs directories in the same project. Below is my current `gulpfile.js`:

```
var package = require('./package.json'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    notify =  require('gulp-notify');

function createSassTask(directory) {
    var taskName = 'sass-'+directory;
    gulp.task(taskName, function() {
        return gulp.src('./'+directory+'/media/sass/**/*.scss')
            .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
            .pipe(autoprefixer('last 4 version'))
            .pipe(minifyCSS({keepBreaks:true}))
            .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min' }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./'+directory+'/media/css'))
            .pipe(notify('SASS compiled for ' + directory));
    });
    gulp.watch('./'+directory+'/media/sass/**/*.scss', [taskName]);
}

gulp.task('default', function () {
    createSassTask('httpdocs-site1');
    createSassTask('httpdocs-site2');
    createSassTask('httpdocs-site3');
});
```

How can I best use sourcemaps with tasks like this? I've tried using `gulp-sourcemaps` but I need to be able to wrap the `init()` and `write()` functions around sass, autoprefixer, minifyCSS and rename. I don't think minifyCSS or rename support `gulp-sourcemaps`. Is there another/better way?

Answer (score 0):

You're dependent on support for sourcemaps on every individual gulp-plugin you use in you pipeline.

A complete table of supported plugins can be found [here](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/wiki/Plugins-with-gulp-sourcemaps-support).

This is a known issue, also for cases where you for example `@import` your Sass files. See this on [GitHub](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/issues/60), where they use an (ugly) way of resolving this by piping the sourcemaps twice, such that it wraps around each plugin so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

When gulp-* plugins (gulp-less, gulp-concat, gulp-minify-css, ...) have [sourcemaps support](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/wiki/Plugins-with-gulp-sourcemaps-support), It "should" work.

My problem was that I have used older versions of those individual gulp-* plugins. Sourcemaps were added later in later versions. Always check that you are using latest version of gulp-* plugins (with sourcemaps support).